Left join to a date range + SQL math with dates
Second week working in SQL and data. I am commenting/documenting views we have in our database and I am so lost on this specific view. I have never seen a join into a date range and am quite puzzled by it. As well as there's some math involving dates that I can't wrap my head around for some reason but I probably just need some more coffee - although some help/advice with it would be much appreciated.
Anyways here it is:
Left Join
    Date1 On Date1 > Date2
          And Date1 < Date3

With this I'm confused what exactly is being left joined. Is Date1 being joined by matching data from the Date2 and Date3 table IF their respective info falls within that date range? Or are Date2 and Date3 being matched by data in Date1 IF it's data falls within this range? There is no key = key match that I am accustomed to with joins.
date1 < GETDATE() + 7 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + 1

With this what trips me up is going from a DD/MM/YYYY and DD format. Date1 is in DD/MM/YYYY, you add 7 (days?) to today (10/16/2024), then subtract by the days value (today is Wednesday so it would be 4) so we get 10/19/2024? Or is it just 19? Then you add one so its 10/20/2024 or just 20? Then is it okay to compare dates if they are in different formats? I am definitely missing the knowledge in this so if anyone could enlighten me on this that would be awesome.

Two rows from the two tables involved in the LEFT JOIN are compared : IF the Date1 from the one table falls into the range defined by Date2 and Date3 from the other table's row, then that joined row is added to the result set. If Date1 is outside the Date2....Date3 range - then the rows is skipped and not added to the result set.

Write the table name or table alias before the column name when selecting from multiple tables, this makes things clear and prevents unexpected issues.

Add a tag for the dbms used. Both GETDATE and DATEPART are product specific functions.

Columns defined as date or datetime are NOT stored in "a format". Internally this data is stored as a set of integers (assuming you are using SQL Server), but when you want to see that data the dbms only then is a format applied so that you will see the date and/or time information according to your culture or preference.  Date/time information is in essence numeric because you need to be able to sort it in very specific ways and you need arithmetic operators. One note of caution: occasionally people do store dates as text - a terrible idea -  but this not appear to be the case for your data.

Regarding the date arithmetic, this is I believe a mechanism to choose data upto the end of the current week. Check out this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/ssW1Roci  which breaks-up that arithmetic into it's parts so you can follow the logic. nb getdate() returns a "datetime" (both date and time of day)  you might need to cast the result of that calculation to "date" instead of "datetime"
